# Rename page URL

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I have the following URL structure:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/gallery?id=331
```

`id` specifies the `id` of the post.

`gallery` is a normal page inside which I am accessing the `id` of the post and fetching the attachment images using `WP_Query()`.

I want to replace the URL of this page to:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/topic/place/new-delhi/gallery?id=331
```

in which the parameters `place` and `new-delhi` may vary in multiple other options and `topic` is the keyword which remains the same.

I have tried using some unfruitful `.htaccess` file code.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell _exactly_ where you've set `topic`, `place`, `new-delhi` and what they are (custom post type/meta data/taxonomy, etc.).

Comment: topic is a page and place is a cpt and new-delhi is a post under 'place' cpt

Comment: _"Please edit your question(...)"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried some add_rewrite_rule magic and query variables and it worked. Thanks for the help everyone.

If in case anyone want to refer the answer:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'custom_gallery_id';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_rewrite_rule(
  'topic/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/gallery/([0-9]+)/?$',
  'index.php?pagename=gallery&custom_gallery_id=$matches[3]',
  'top' );
```

I was able to solve my problem with this.